# database insert/updates in an event-driven matter in nodejs

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, events

Nodejs preaches approaching everything in an event-driven matter.

A simple solution to monitoring changes on a database is to just poll it on a separate thread. Is there an event-based equivalent? How does one approach monitoring a db for changes in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution with regards to this, will ultimately be a form of

```
var interval = 1000;
setInterval(function(){
  db.find(function(err, data){
    // check data for changes
  })

}, interval);
```

You can get fancy with other features, such as cancellers, retries etc. But it will ultimately be just a timer that emits an event, to which a callback is attached. setInterval does just that.